# Is an XAML file portable to Xamarin Macintosh?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

I don't have access to a Macintosh to test this on (i.e, I can't load the Xamarin Mac components) so I don't have a way to test this. But...below is the XAML of a WPF app. Most everything in the app appears to be Xamarin-compliant -- WebClient calls, populating my form fields through an XMLDocument and binding, for instance -- but I don't know of the XAML is compliant. So, here it is:

```
<Window x:Class="IMManager.ImManagerWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="IMM Media Manager" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
    WindowState="Normal" 
    MaxWidth="720" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AlternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <!-- setting row height here -->
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="LvAlbums" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/downloads/Album}" Width="680">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="dt1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="spAlbum" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding XPath=@Artist,StringFormat='Artist: {0}'}"
                    FontSize="16px"
                    />
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding XPath=@Name,StringFormat='Album: {0}'}"
                    FontSize="16px"
                    />
                <ListView x:Name="lvTracks" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"   AlternationCount="2">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Track" Width="460">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="trackName" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Width="450" LineHeight="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Progress" Width="175">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25">
                                            <ProgressBar Foreground="GreenYellow" Name="PbStatus" Value="{Binding XPath=@Progress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="165"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" LineHeight="25" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding XPath=@Info, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="165" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Can Mac Xamarin handle this or something close to this?

Answer (score 3):

No.  Xamarin Mac does not use XAML.  Xamarin Forms does, but it is a different syntax than the XAML used in WPF.

Comment: What about the general controls like listview, gridview, etc? Do they exist and function the same way vis-à-vis binding, for instance?

The way my progress bar works is that I have an XML document that gets updated during the download process. An <Item> attribute named "Progess" gets updated with the percent complete and the XAML progress bar is bound to that attribute and is able to display the progress. Am I going to have to do that differently for the Mac?

Comment: There are some similar controls, but they're not going to be identical to Windows desktop controls.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I spent about 16 hours developing this app and I've got a developer who says it's going to take close to 200 hours to do the same thing in Xamarin Mac. I just can't believe that it can be that complicated. I'm trying to develop a common code base for Windows/Mac/Android and iOS for downloading files and the code I developed -- using WebClient, an XML Document and control bindings -- seems to be fairly universal to those 4 platforms. No platform-dependent APIs, for instance. I'm a little stuck? I guess at this point.

Comment: Depending on your timeframe, you may want to consider Xamarin Forms.  It is supposed to add Mac desktop support in a future release.  It already supports UWP (but not WPF).  I agree that 200 hours seems high.  Contact me (see my profile) if you want a 2nd opinion.